# AngularJS - watcher triggers callback during reload/router change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why the watch callback is called upon browser reload or angular route change even when the oldvalue and newvalue are the same. For example

```
$scope.test = "blah"; 
$scope.watch("test", function(new,old){
  console.log(new === old);
}
```

You will see true in console log any time you reload the page or the route changed away and back to that controller. I had to add a guard inside the callback to avoid unnecessary callbacks. Is there anything I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answer above from Mathew Berg, I found the answer in the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch)

> After a watcher is registered with the scope, the listener fn is
>   called asynchronously (via $evalAsync) to initialize the watcher. In
>   rare cases, this is undesirable because the listener is called when
>   the result of watchExpression didn't change. To detect this scenario
>   within the listener fn, you can compare the newVal and oldVal. If
>   these two values are identical (===) then the listener was called due
>   to initialization.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the documentation [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch) they talk about when this happens. It really depends on how the rest of your app is set up, but just doing a quick check via === will let you know if it's changed or not (which they suggest)